# How to find the Nodejs module path?

Tags: node.js

I have required a module say 'fs'
fs = require('fs');

And it is loaded successfully. But how can I check the path on my windows for this module?

Answer (score 0):

Three ways of requiring modules in NodeJs

1)node-modules directory in your project structure
Ex:`var promise = require('bluebird');`

2)If step 1 fails Nodejs checks in core modules.
Node.js comes with many modules compiled directly into the executable binary (ex. http, fs, sys, events, path, etc.).

3) If you write your own module you need to specify absolute path of that module
Ex:`var logger = require('../../logger')`

Comment: I can load successfully but I want to know the path where the module reside in my windows.

Comment: Those modules are bundled in .exe file . refer                                                       https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2169-where-does-node-js-and-require-look-for-modules.htm

Comment: Check, but not very helpful.